# Return statement on multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have scoured the interwebs trying to figure this out but with no luck. As far as I know you usually only have one return statement however my problem is that I need to have line breaks in my return statement in order for the testing to return 'true'. What I've tried is throwing up errors, probably just a rookie mistake. My current function with no attempts to make a line break is below.

```
def game(word, con):
   return (word + str('!')
   word + str(',') + word + str(phrase1)
```

Are new line breaks (\n) supposed to work in return statements? It's not in my testing.

Comment: "I need to have line breaks in my return statement in order for the testing to return 'true'" - no, you don't. Most likely, you want a line break in the string you're returning, not in the return statement itself. That can be done with `'\n'`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In python, an open paren causes subsequent lines to be considered a part of the same line until a close paren.

So you can do:

```
def game(word, con):
    return (word + str('!') +
            word + str(',') +
            word + str(phrase1))
```

But I wouldn't recommend that in this particular case. I mention it since it's syntactically valid and you might use it elsewhere.

Another thing you can do is use the backslash:

```
def game(word, con):
    return word + '!' + \
           word + ',' + \
           word + str(phrase)
    # Removed the redundant str('!'), since '!' is a string literal we don't need to convert it
```

Or, in this particular case, my advice would be to use a formatted string.

```
def game(word, con):
    return "{word}!{word},{word}{phrase1}".format(
        word=word, phrase1=phrase1")
```

That looks like it's functionally equivalent to what you're doing in yours but I can't really know. The latter is what I'd do in this case though.

If you want a line break in the STRING, then you can use "\n" as a string literal wherever you need it.

```
def break_line():
    return "line\nbreak"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split up a line in a return statement, but you have forgotten a parenthesis at the end and that you also need to separate it with another operator (in this case, a `+`)

Change:

```
def game(word, con):
   return (word + str('!')
   word + str(',') + word + str(phrase1)
```

To:

```
def game(word, con):
   return (word + str('!') + # <--- plus sign
   word + str(',') + word + str(phrase1))
#                                       ^ Note the extra parenthesis
```

---

Note that calling `str()` on `'!'` and `','` is pointless. They are already strings.

Answer (score 1):

First - you're using str() to convert several strings to strings. This is not neccessary.

Second - there's nothing in your code that would insert a newline in the string you're building. Just having a newline in the middle of the string doesn't add a newline, you need to do that explicitly.

I think that what you're trying to do would be something like this:

```
def game(word, con):
    return (word + '!' + '\n' +
        word + ',' + word + str(phrase1))
```

I'm leaving in the call to `str(phrase1)` since I don't know what phrase1 is - if it's already a string<strike>, or has a `.__str__()` method</strike> this shouldn't be needed.

I'm assuming that the string you're trying to build spans the two lines, so I've added the missing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: `__str__` doesn't get autoinvoked when you try to add a non-string to a string. You need to call `str`, which will invoke `__str__`, or `__repr__` if there is no `__str__`.

Answer (score 1):

the simple code to understand

```
def sentence():
    return print('ankit \nkalauni is\n the\n new\n learner\n in\n programming')
sentence()
```

the output:
ankit
kalauni
is
the
new
learner
in
programming

easy peasy way to return the multiple lines in python